# What is the name of this USB form factor?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, form-factor

I saw several news articles about the [YuibKey](https://www.yubico.com/product/security-key-by-yubico/) several years ago, and always thought the way it was shaped was really cool. Instead of requiring a [box-shaped connection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001T99ZTI) like normal USB-A, it is a single flat piece. I want a flash drive in this form factor, like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00512P52K) Verbatim drive or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MCB54Y) Super Talent drive. It appears that Kingston made or makes [a product in this form factor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0028R3NCU), but it's a SD reader not flash storage. Is there a name for this form factor that I can use while searching for a product like this?

Comment: It isn't a different or special form factor.  It's just the guts of a USB-A connector without the shroud.

Comment: As @fixer1234 says, yes, USB without a shroud, which violates USB specifications, because it exposes sensitive data signals to direct ESD events, while the shroud usually gets the ESD hit first protecting the data lines. So it is a bad idea to search and use these devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official or common name that I've ever seen referenced. A quick search shows that "caseless usb drive" and "usb drive exposed contacts|connector" gives you some hits on what you want.

Comment: That's a shame. I was hoping for something a little more concrete, but this seems like the correct answer. Thanks for your help!